# SSRS Reporting Services, ASP Report Viewer Rendering With Large Gaps/Spaces

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have an ASP.Net project with a report viewer (v11) pulling remote SSRS reports from a 2008 R2 Reporting Server.

The issue is when the reports are rendered in the Report Viewer control, there are large gaps/spaces between the report's charts and tables.

The reports render perfectly with no gaps or spaces when run from the report server or from visual studio (SSRS).

Has anybody experienced an issue similar to this?  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Similar issues across common browsers (IE8 - 11, Google Chrome)

Comment: Have you tried setting the report property: `ConsumeContainerWhitespace = true`?

Comment: I ass**u**me that your issue isn't due to hidden objects. When all else fails, have you tried putting the objects in a **Rectangle**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

Ironically, I discovered the cause of the error when my web app's CSS class failed to load.  With no CSS, the reports rendered perfectly on the web page! I knew that the report viewer renders the report using HTML  so I simply deleted all the 'table' related CSS that was auto generated when I originally created the web forms project.

Thanks for the suggestions:)